# Sequelize Association Modal

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm still learning sequelize and had my association working as intended. My original set up was having a 'History' modal that belonged to a user modal and a video model, so that a specific user had its own video history. This was working and returned the proper userId connected to the video:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const History = sequelize.define("History", {})

    History.associate = function (models) {
        History.belongsTo(models.User)
        History.belongsTo(models.Video)
    }

    return History
}
```

I'm having issues implementing a new feature that stores the time in the video when the user stopped watching. I have the correct information being passed into the modal, but am getting issues like: VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3);
The goal is to add a 'time' property to that association. Here is how I implemented it:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const History = sequelize.define("History", { 
        Time: { 
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE, 
            field: 'time' 
        } 
    })

    
    History.associate = function (models) {
        History.belongsTo(models.User)
        History.belongsTo(models.Video)
    }

    return History
}
```

```
async post(req, res) {
        async post(req, res) {
        try {
            console.log(req.body)//ex. { videoId: 9, userId: 2, time: 34.21701037002167 }
            console.log(Object.keys(History.rawAttributes));

            const videoId = req.body.videoId
            const userId = req.body.userId
            const time = (req.body.time).toFixed(2)

            const newHistory = await History.create({
                VideoId: videoId,
                UserId: userId,
                Time: time,
            })

            res.send(newHistory)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send({
                error: '500: Error trying to create history'
            })
        }
    }
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

err:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Histories` (`id`,`time`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`UserId`,`VideoId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `time` AS `Time`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `UserId`, `VideoId` FROM `Histories` AS `History` WHERE `History`.`userId` = '2';
Error
    at Database.<anonymous> (C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:185:27)
    at C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:183:50
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Query.run (C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:183:12)
    at C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:314:28
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SQLiteQueryInterface.insert (C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:308:21)
    at async model.save (C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2432:35)
    at async History.create (C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1344:12)
    at async post (C:\Users\19bkm\Documents\GitHub\Senior-Project-v2\server\src\controllers\HistoriesController.js:32:32) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table Histories has no column named time] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `Histories` (`id`,`time`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`UserId`,`VideoId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);'
  },
  original: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table Histories has no column named time] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `Histories` (`id`,`time`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`UserId`,`VideoId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);'
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `Histories` (`id`,`time`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`UserId`,`VideoId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);',
  parameters: {}
}
::1 - - [03/Mar/2023:20:46:48 +0000] "POST /histories HTTP/1.1" 500 47 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  }
```

Here is my GET method:

```
async index(req, res) {
        try {
            const userId = req.query.userId
            const history = await History.findAll({
                where: {
                    userId: userId
                }
            })

            res.send(history)
        } catch (err) {

            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send({
                error: '500: Error trying to get history '
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `time` field added to the table in DB?

Comment: What exact error and stacktrace did you get?

Comment: [ 'id', 'time', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'UserId', 'VideoId' ] @Anatoly the field does appear to be there

Comment: Show the `err` content

Comment: @Anatoly added the err to end of the post, thanks for the help!

Comment: Then just indicate `field: 'time'` in the definition of `time` prop in the model

Comment: How should the model look then? I'm putting it within 'time', right under the DataTypes.DOUBLE, still gives the no column err @Anatoly

Comment: The case matters: indicate `field: 'time'` and not `field: 'Time'`

Comment: I've tried a few variations, but no success yet. I've updated the new code and err log. Thanks for the replies @Anatoly

Comment: This time it could because you named it as `time` (could be possible reserved word for SQLite).. Try to rename the filed in DB and in the model as well

Comment: Same error still. Could it be due to changing an existing model? Would making a new table completely help?

Comment: Hard to say. Did you try to execute the generated SQL against DB?

Comment: Got it to work! I used DB Browser and manually changed the table. The code is correct, as I didn't change anything and it adds data properly. Could have been wanting me to migrate the old data to the new model, preventing me from added the column? I appreciate your patience and walking me through debugging, I learned a lot! Thanks @Anatoly